# how to make scaffold template add new custom views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates, customization, scaffold

Scaffold MVC default genaration for default Views template as :

```
_CreateOrEdit
Edit
Create
Index
```

Now I want to create Template like

```
_CreateOrEdit
Edit
Create
Index
and new template _Index as subview in Index for PageListMVC
```

Could you suggest to me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Go to:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 4\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML

2.) Copy that folder into your Solution and put it inside a folder called "CodeTemplates"

3.) Delete every file inside except List.tt
(I wouldn't have files in this folder unless you are using them. Once you are done with this one you can repeat the process for each of the other files originally in this folder.)

4.) In the properties for the List.tt file change

```
Build Action: NONE
Browse To Url: BLANK
Copy to Output Dir: DO NOT COPY
```

5.) Rename the file to List_Div  and then Edit the file to work how you want. And when you then go to scaffold List_Div will be a new option. YOu have to do this for every project you want this functionality for. But I just copy the directory into each project when I start a new one. I have a Views folder specifically for Bootstrap projct, FOundatons Projects, etc....

I will give you an example of what my Foundation List_F5 file looks like, I am only going to show you the lines that are important to change (approximately line 49 through 128:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title><#= mvcHost.ViewName #></title>
</head>
<body>
<#
    PushIndent("    ");
}
#>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
<#
List<ModelProperty> properties = GetModelProperties(mvcHost.ViewDataType);
foreach (ModelProperty property in properties) {
    if (!property.IsPrimaryKey && property.Scaffold) {
#>
        <div class="medium-1 columns">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.<#= property.ValueExpression #>)
        </div>
<#
    }
}
#>
        <div class="medium-3 columns"></div>
    </div>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
<#
foreach (ModelProperty property in properties) {
    if (!property.IsPrimaryKey && property.Scaffold) {
#>
        <div class="medium-1 columns">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => <#= property.ItemValueExpression #>)
        </div>
<#
    }
}

string pkName = GetPrimaryKeyName(mvcHost.ViewDataType);
if (pkName != null) {
#>
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.<#= pkName #> })"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> |
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Details", new { id=item.<#= pkName #> })"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></a> |
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.<#= pkName #> })"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
<#
} else {
#>
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a> |
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })"><i class="fa fa-file"></i></a> |
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </div>
<#
}
#>
    </div>
}

</div>
<#
// The following code closes the asp:Content tag used in the case of a master page and the body and html tags in the case of a regular view page
#>
<#
if(mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
#>
<#
} else if(!mvcHost.IsPartialView && !mvcHost.IsContentPage) {
    ClearIndent();
#>
</body>
</html>
```